# типы данных short

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       for (short i = 32766; i<032767; i++){
           System.out.println(i);
       }
}}
```

Что выведется в консоли и почему? Разве не должно один раз выводиться `32767`?

Comment: @AlexChermenin  а какую это выдает ошибку: 1) iteration don't execute; 2)compile error; 3) runtime error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего не будет выведено.

1. Числа, начинающиеся с 0 в Java представляют собой числа в восмеричной системе счисления и `032767` равняется числу `13815` в десятичной.
2. Максимальное положительное значение типа `short` равно `32767`, таким образом значение `32766` помещается в переменную без изменений.
3. Число `32766` больше, чем `13815` (или `032767` в восмеричной системе счисления), что не удовлетворяет условию, при котором тело цикла будет выполнено.

Comment: а какую это выдает ошибку: 1) iteration don't execute; 2)compile error; 3) runtime error

Comment: Это не выдаёт никаких ошибок. Вариант `iteration don't execute` как раз означает, что _тело цикла не будет выполнено_.

Answer (score 2):

Ничего.
032767 означает восьмеричный 32767, что явно меньше, чем 32766, поэтому программа ни разу не отработает тело цикла.